# React router que conflict with set setSearchParams

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When using a redirect with `<Navigation/>` together with `setSearchParams` from `react-router-dom` no navigation is executed.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes />
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
const Routes = () => {
  const [, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({});

  useEffect(() => {        
    setSearchParams({ lang: "test" });
  }, [setSearchParams]);

  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Outlet />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "",
          element: <Navigate replace to={`/page`} />
        },
        {
          path: `/page`,
          element: <h1>Page</h1>
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);
};
```

If i add a `setTimeout(() => {setSearchParams({lang})},0)`
The redirect/navigation starts working. the param lang still works as before.

[SANDBOX EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wilson-wkqhxr?file=/src/App.tsx)

A [ISSUE](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10948) is also reported here

Comment: I don't see any issue with the routing code *other than* the route redirecting to `"/security"` should be an `index` route. The `Outlet` component hasn't anything to do with "triggering" anything upon navigation. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? In the meantime, does this [post](/a/70438694/8690857) help answer your question?

Comment: @DrewReese Seems that the setSearchParams interferes with the router

Comment: `useSearchParams` only updates the URL search string and issues a navigation action, the `Outlet` isn't part of this logic. What is `Routes` in the `App` component?

Comment: @DrewReese It's just a regular useRoute
`export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes(Routes)
}` And when adding a timeout 0 to setSearchParams it works too...

Comment: Ok, can you create a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could take a look at?

Comment: @DrewReese Updated with a sandbox example

Comment: Ok, I see now. Yeah, it certainly looks like the redirect from `"/"` to `"/page"` is enqueued at the same time (*with regards to the React component render cycle*) as the search params update is enqueued to set the `"lang"` search param... last one executed is what you see. This seems like a bug and my suggestion for now would be to search for, or open, a [github issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues) with the maintainers. This [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10103) is very similar.

Comment: Looks like this has been an "issue" since at least v6.3.0. Yeah, it's the ordering of when the navigation actions are effected. Using the `setTimeout` with 0 delay is enough to push the search param update to be *after* the `Navigate` redirection.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also say that I'd place use the setTimeout on the `setSearchParams` call in the effect instead of updating a value used as a React key on the `Outlet` since that necessarily unmounts and remounts an entire ReactTree.